# Swapping between layers in kineticJS

Tags: html, html5-canvas, draw, layer, kineticjs

I'm trying to treat layers as pages -- i.e. I draw on one page, then turn the page and draw on another, each time storing the previous page in case the user goes back to it.

In my mind this translates as:

- Create `current_layer` global pointer.
- Each time `newPage()` is called, store the old layer in an array, and overwrite the pointer

  `layer_array.push(current_layer); //store old layer`

  `current_layer = new Kinetic.Layer(); //overwrite with a new`
- New objects are then added to the `current_layer` which binds them to the layer, whether they are drawn or not. (e.g. `current_layer.add(myCircle)` )
- Retrieving a page is simply updating the pointer to the requesting layer in the array, and redrawing the page. All the child nodes attached to the layer will also be drawn too

  `current_layer = layer_array[num-1]; //num is Page 2 e.g`

  `current_layer.draw()`

However nothing is happening! I can create new pages, and store them appropriately - but I cannot retrieve them again...

Here's my full code (my browser is having problems using jsfiddle):

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      //Global
      var stage; //canvas
      var layer_array = [];
      var current_page; //pointer to current layer

      window.onload = function() {
        stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 400,
          height: 400
        });

        //Add initial page to stage to draw on
        newPage()

      };

      //--- Functions ----//

        function newPage(){
            if(!current_page){
                console.log("current page undefined");

            } else {
                layer_array.push(current_page);
//              stage.remove(current_page); 

                //Nope, not working.
                stage.removeChildren();        
                //Works, but I think it unbinds all objects
                // from their specific layers...
//              stage.draw()

                console.log("Stored layer and removed it from stage");
            }
            current_page = new Kinetic.Layer();
            console.log("Currently on page:"+(layer_array.length+1));

            stage.add(current_page);
            stage.draw();

        }


        function gotoPage(num){
            stage.removeChildren()
            stage.draw()

            num = num-1;
            if(num >= 0) {
                current_page = layer_array[num];
                console.log("Now on page"+(num+1));

                stage.add(current_page);
                stage.draw();
            }

        }


        function addCircletoCurrentPage() 
        {
            var rand = Math.floor(3+(Math.random()*10));

            var obj = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: rand*16, y: rand*16,
                radius: rand,
                fill: 'red'
            })

            var imagelayer = current_page;
            imagelayer.add(obj);
            imagelayer.draw();
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button onclick="addCircletoCurrentPage()" >click</button>
    <button onclick="newPage()" >new</button>
    <button onclick="gotoPage(1)" >page1</button>
    <button onclick="gotoPage(2)" >page2</button>
    <button onclick="gotoPage(3)" >page3</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun problem. I think this fixes your troubles: http://jsfiddle.net/LRNHk/3/

Basically, you shouldn't remove() or removeChildren() as you risk de-referencing them.

Instead you should use:

```
   layer.hide();  and  layer.show();
```

this way, you keep all things equal and you get speedy draw performance.
So your go to page function should be like this:

```
    function gotoPage(num){
       for(var i=0; i<layer_array.length; i++) {
            layer_array[i].hide();
       }
          layer_array[num].show();
          console.log("Currently on page:"+(num));
          console.log("Current layer: " + layer_array[num].getName());
          stage.draw();
    }
```

I also modified your other functions, which you can see in the jsfiddle.

Comment: You sir, are a ninja. Thank you very much! Let me test it out before I tick you

Comment: Yep verified -- I've seen some of your questions around on KineticJS, you must be pretty handy with it by now

Comment: Also, you'll notice that the jsfiddle doesn't completely solve the issue, as adding elements and flipping through pages may not give you perfect results. You have to fiddle with the logic of adding elements to a certain layer.

Comment: also just a small issue with your `gotoPage(num)` method where you didn't update the `current_page` pointer to equal the new shown layer. Small issue I know, but for future users

Answer (score -1):

Okay I changed my approach and instead of swapping layers (100x easier and makes more sense), I instead opted for serializing the entire stage and loading it back.

It works, but it really shouldn't have to be like this dammit

```
  //Global
  var stage; //canvas
  var layer_array = [];
  var current_page; //pointer to current layer
  var page_num = 0;

  window.onload = function() {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 400,
      height: 400
    });

    //Add initial page to stage to draw on
    newPage()

  };

  //--- Functions ----//

    function newPage(){
        if(!current_page){
            console.log("current page undefined");

        } else {
            savePage(page_num)
            stage.removeChildren()

            console.log("Stored layer and removed it from stage");
        }
        current_page = new Kinetic.Layer();
        console.log("Currently on page:"+(layer_array.length+1));

        stage.add(current_page);
        stage.draw();

        page_num ++;

    }

    function savePage(num){
        if( (num-1) >=0){
            var store = stage.toJSON();
            layer_array[num-1] = store;
            console.log("Stored page:"+num)
        }
    }

    function gotoPage(num){
        savePage(page_num);

        stage.removeChildren()

        if(num-1 >= 0) {
            var load = layer_array[num-1];
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = ""; //blank
            stage = Kinetic.Node.create(load, 'container');

            var images = stage.get(".image");

            for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
            {  
            //function to induce scope
                (function() {
                    var image = images[i];
                    var imageObj = new Image();
                    imageObj.onload = function() {
                        image.setImage(imageObj);
                        current_page.draw();
                    };
                    imageObj.src = image.attrs.src;
                })();
            }
            stage.draw();
            page_num =num //update page

        }
    }

    function addCircletoCurrentPage() 
    {
        var rand = Math.floor(3+(Math.random()*10));

        var obj = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: rand*16, y: rand*16, name: "image",
            radius: rand,
            fill: 'red'
        })

        var imagelayer = current_page;
        imagelayer.add(obj);
        imagelayer.draw();
    }
```

Comment: Agreed, too kludgy -- your method is perfect